# Best tool for multiple unattended or silent installation

Tags: installation

I'm currently looking for a software which could provide silent installation for various software.

Software like Ninite etc. are very typical, whereas I think of a defined set of software I use for software development (Visual Studio, Perforce etc.).

I would like to customize it, so that the user can select which software will be installed depending upon platform.

Suggestions for Software Pulling and Software Pushing both welcomed!

Comment: I was after a similar tool but no such tool exists AFAIK. I will be open sourcing my tool soon.

Comment: @thegreendroid: Any progress here?

Comment: @gentlesea The tool that we wrote wasn't very robust. I ended up using a tool called Chocolatey instead. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/), it is a really flexible, scriptable installation platform based on the NuGet Package Manager (almost like apt-get for Windows).